# How can I adjust the huse, saturation, and lightness of in image in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, hsl

The simplest method possible is preferable. I unfortunately don't know much about image manipulation!

Comment: The answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218783/javascript-canvas-pixel-manipulation seems helpful and it has this http://jsfiddle.net/9GLNP/ - It's a little glitchy for me, but reload the page enough and it will work eventually

Comment: `canvasContext.getImageData()` and `canvasContext.putImageData()` are what you'll be using if it's based on what's on the canvas already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `globalCompositeOperation` ,`"hue"`,`"saturation"`,`"color"`, and `"luminosity"`

Where

- "hue" will change the destination hue to the hue to that of the source.
- "saturation" will change the destination saturation to that of the source
- "color" will change the destination color to that of the source.
- "luminosity" will change the destination luminosity to that of the source

For example if you want to change the image saturation to full saturation

```
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); // image to change
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(0,100%,50%)";  // saturation at 100%
ctx.fillRect(0,0,image.width,image.height);  // apply the comp filter
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";  // restore default comp
```

If you want finer control you will have to do it pixel by pixel using `getImageData` and `setimagedata` but this can be very slow. For speed you are best to use a webGL filter that will compare to the above comp modes in terms of speed, but the trade off is code complexity.